# memcmp sort

Tags: c++, c, performance, sorting, stl

I have a single buffer, and several pointers into it.  I want to sort the pointers based upon the bytes in the buffer they point at.

qsort() and stl::sort() can be given custom comparision functions.  For example, if the buffer was zero-terminated I could use strcmp:

```
int my_strcmp(const void* a,const void* b) {
  const char* const one = *(const char**)a,
  const two = *(const char**)b;
  return ::strcmp(one,two);
}
```

however, if the buffer is not zero-terminated, I have to use memcmp() which requires a length parameter.

Is there a tidy, efficient way to get the length of the buffer into my comparision function without a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't null-terminate your buffers?

If not, since you're using C++ you can write your own function object:

```
 struct MyStrCmp {
    MyStrCmp (int n): length(n) { }
    inline bool operator< (char *lhs, char *rhs) {
       return ::strcmp (lhs, rhs, length);
    }
    int length;
 };
 // ...
 std::sort (myList.begin (), myList.end (), MyStrCmp (STR_LENGTH));
```

Comment: Note: std::sort takes iterators **not** containers.

Comment: haha!  -- at least you got the std::sort call correct .. forgot about iterators ;)

Comment: thanks, you're accepted answer since you answered slightly faster than Evan, and Evan has *tons* of points already.
I put a working version Evan's comments; pls update your code too?

Comment: @Will: aww, rep bias :(. Oh well, no hard feelings, glad you were able to get a working solution.

Answer (score 7):

With std::sort, you can use a Functor like this:

```
struct CompString {
    CompString(int len) : m_Len(len) {}
    bool operator<(const char *a, const char *b) const {
        return std::memcmp(a, b, m_Len);
    }
private:
    int m_Len;
};
```

Then you can do this:

```
std::sort(begin(), end(), CompString(4)); // all strings are 4 chars long
```

**EDIT:** from the comment suggestions (i guess both strings are in a common buffer?):

```
struct CompString {
    CompString (const unsigned char* e) : end(e) {}
    bool operator()(const unsigned char *a, const unsigned char *b) const {
        return std::memcmp(a, b, std::min(end - a, end - b)) < 0;
    }
private:
    const unsigned char* const end;
};
```

Comment: struct CompString {
     CompString (const unsigned char* e) : end(e) {}
  bool operator()(const unsigned char *a, const unsigned char *b) const {
         return (-1 == ::memcmp(a, b, __min(end-a,end-b)));
  }
 private:
  const unsigned char* const end;
 };

Comment: This approach got me started.

I just posted some minor corrections.  Pls update the code.

Comment: I couldn't get the operator< to compile, but with a functor overloading the (), it worked a charm!

Comment: for the sake of completeness, I should say that my solution failed to account for when the bytes matched - as far as the end of the buffer, but obviously one string would be longer than the other...

Comment: well you implied in the original request that all strings being compared were the same length...

Comment: yeah my bad, its all about BWT, but I didn't want to derail this with a discussion about the best ways to do BWT

Answer (score 4):

With the C function `qsort()`, no, there is no way to pass the length to your comparison function without using a global variable, which means it can't be done in a thread-safe manner.  Some systems have a [`qsort_r()`](http://www.ipnom.com/FreeBSD-Man-Pages/qsort_r.3.html) function (*r* stands for reentrant) which allows you to pass an extra *context* parameter, which then gets passed on to your comparison function:

```
int my_comparison_func(void *context, const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return memcmp(*(const void **)a, *(const void **)b, (size_t)context);
}

qsort_r(data, n, sizeof(void*), (void*)number_of_bytes_to_compare, &my_comparison_func);
```

Comment: BSD systems, including MacOS X, include qsort_r(); it appears other platforms do not.

Answer (score 2):

Can you pack your buffer pointer + length into a structure and pass a pointer of that structure as `void *`?

Comment: You create a new array of these structures and sort that using a custom comparison function. If you must access the original array (instead of the underlying data), you can maintain pointers or indexes from the new array to the old, which you can use after it is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hack like:

```
int buffcmp(const void *b1, const void *b2)
{
    static int bsize=-1;
    if(b2==NULL) {bsize=*(int*)(b1); return 0;}
    return memcmp(b1, b2, idsize);
}
```

which you would first call as `buffcmp(&bsize, NULL)` and then pass it as the comparison function to `qsort`.

You could of course make the comparison behave more naturally in the case of `buffcmp(NULL, NULL)` etc by adding more `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could functors (give the length to the functor's constructor) or Boost.Lambda (use the length in-place).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear on what you're asking. But I'll try, assuming that

- You have a single buffer
- You have an array of pointers of some kind which has been processed in some way so that some or all of its contents point into the buffer

That is code equivalent to:

```
char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*bufsize);
for (int i=0; i<bufsize; ++i){
    buf[i] = some_cleverly_chosen_value(i);
}

char *ary[arraysize] = {0};
for(int i=0; i<arraysize; ++i){
   ary[i] = buf + some_clever_function(i);
}

/* ...do the sort here */
```

Now if you control the allocation of the buffer, you could substitute

```
char *buf = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(bufsize+1));
buf[bufsize]='\0';
```

and go ahead using strcmp. This may be possible even if you don't control the filling of the buffer.

If you have to live with a buffer handed you by someone else you can

1. Use some global storage (which you asked to avoid and good thinking).
2. Hand the sort function something more complicated than a raw pointer (the address of a struct or class that supports the extra data). For this you need to control the deffinition of `ary` in the above code.
3. Use a sort function which supports an extra input. Either `sort_r` as suggested by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583063/memcmp-sort/583125#583125), or a home-rolled solution (which I do recommend as an exercise for the student, and don't recommend in real life). In either case the extra data is probably a pointer to the end of the buffer.

Comment: What?!? The problem statement _is_ unclear. One byte? Two bytes? Up to the end of the buffer? That value of the pointer? All of these are valid understandings of what Will has written.

Comment: Second sentence: "I want to sort the pointers based upon the bytes in the buffer they point at."  OP is asking how to pass the buffer size into the sorting routine's comparison function.  Your answer provides nothing helpful in that regard.

Comment: I really don't find that to be clear at all. I'm convince that he means from the pointer to the end because he's not complaining about other answers that use that meaning, but... ANyway, I'll work up an answer on that basis.

Answer (score -2):

`memcmp` should stop on the first byte that is unequal, so the length should be large, i.e. to-the-end-of-the-buffer. Then the only way it can return zero is if it does go to the end of the buffer.

(BTW, I lean toward merge sort myself. It's stable and well-behaved.)

Comment: Yes, but how does memcmp() know how big the buffer is?  That is the problem at hand.

Comment: I guess that's just a plumbing problem. You can't do any worse that writing your own merge sort and passing along any information you care to.